# bootstrap modal not working from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to add a modal to dropdown menu but it won't work unless I click it twice or add a closing div to it.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="bs-example">
<form>
    <!--Default buttons with dropdown menu-->
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a  href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">edit</a></li>  <!-- i dont want to add a div here -->


             <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And [**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zynxqdxx/2/) it might explain better

The modal doesn't come up after clicking on "edit". You have to click Action once again for it to come up.

Comment: Note your `form` is not closed, implying invalid HTML. Best fix the HTML first.

Comment: its closed in my main code and it dosnt work

Comment: You have a DIV as a child of a UL which is not valid. That caused the main problem. Bart Jedrocha has bypassed those errors in his example below.

Comment: oh now i get what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of invalid HTML. Here is an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zynxqdxx/3/) with working behaviour.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    The modal dosnt come up after clicking on "edit". you have to click Action once again for it to come up
<div class="bs-example">
    <form>
        <!--Default buttons with dropdown menu-->
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a  href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">edit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
        <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you didn't close your list

Add:

```
</ul>
```

After your last

```
<li></li>
```

Comment: This wasn't the only HTML issue, so well done on 3 upvotes :)

Comment: You are right, it wasn't.. but it was the issue that would resolve the original question of why the modal wasn't activating on the first click.  Solving all the HTML issues wasn't the real question. ;)

Comment: Without a JSFiddle, that was/is guesswork on your part (and the voters) that that one fix actually solves the problem. Best try your solution yourself and see :)

Comment: I tried it myself... no need to post a JSFiddle for such a straightforward and simple solution.  Perhaps take your own advice and don't do guesswork on my tested solution ;)

Comment: *If* you have checked the JSFiddle provided by the OP, you might have noticed the `</ul>` *was already in the page*, just after the div. Moving the `div` would have been a more sensible answer. Tested... bah! :)

Comment: Still need to research for what was the problem actually. You guys argue with each other without mentioning the only thing that finally matters.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my early comment: Based on the JSFiddle you provide (as the HTML above is incomplete), a more accurate answer would be that you had a `div` as a child of the `UL`. That is not valid. Only `LI`s may be children of a `UL`.

Also you had not closed your form element.

Formatting *your existing HTML* (using the `tidyup` button in JSFiddle) would look like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zynxqdxx/6/

Solution: That `div` simply needed to be moved outside the `UL` to be valid HTML and the `</form>` needed to be added.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zynxqdxx/5/

**Formatted Html:**

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <form>
        <!--Default buttons with dropdown menu-->
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">edit</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- i dont want to add a div here -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                             <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                            <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small>

                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

***General advice:*** work with well formatted HTML so you can spot errors like this